# Adding object of the array at different length javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array` which looks like

```
[
    { "Fare":10, "TotalFare":30 },
    { "Fare":20, "TotalFare":50 },
    { "Fare":30, "TotalFare":100 }
]
```

now I want to add  these fare in one variable at the index of 0

like when i write `array[0].fare` i should get total i.e `60`

yes i know i can do this with for loop
like `array[0].fare += array[i].fare`

but is there any better way to do this,

> because my array consists of 64/65 columns which I have to add and it will be very long if I write like the above,

what should I do here?

Comment: at least, you need to loop somwhere. please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method in combination with `Object.keys`.

```js
let arr = [ { "Fare":10, "TotalFare":30 }, { "Fare":20, "TotalFare":50 }, { "Fare":30, "TotalFare":100 } ]

arr[0] = Object.keys(arr[0]).reduce(function(obj, key){
  obj[key] = arr.map(a => a[key]).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
  return obj;
},{});
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc.fare + val; });
```

I have not tested this but I guess you should be able to use array.reduce and simplify your solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a new object at index `0` of the array using `unshift()` then you can use a `forEach()` loop as below:

```js
var arr = [
    { "Fare":10, "TotalFare":30 },
    { "Fare":20, "TotalFare":50 },
    { "Fare":30, "TotalFare":100 }
];
arr.unshift({"Fare":0});
arr.forEach(obj=>arr[0].Fare += obj.Fare);
console.log(arr[0].Fare);
```